# Datagrid design in Wpf (xaml)

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am wondering how I can achieve this in datagrid wpf 
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Please add some sample code done by you. This is not a paid forum where you can get someone to get your work done for. Please try out with some examples from the internet and post the code here if you require any assistance.

Comment: I am working with this. Just need some suggestions how can achieve this between the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that requires styling row headers. You can do it inside the Datagrid, which is to me the proper way:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        ....> Your template here <
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Or you can apply a style defined in your resources.

Comment: There are other things you could do, but this is the simplest for a starter. As vishakh369 pointed out, your question was quite broad, so you got a broad answer. Usually we use this site to solve more specific and tricky questions, but its ok if my answer was useful. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: But I didn't ask for the whole. Indicated with arrow. Even I am mature enough that It is not a tutorial website.. Your answer was simple and straightforward. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if I was rude.  Yes what natxo said is right. Try to be more specific. Good answer @Natxo